# Python - Converter object in time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time, converters

I am trying to convert the time below to the format HH:MM:SS.

```
PXTIMEFLOWSTARTED_TIME

40538.22
131725.529
```

I am using:

```
dataset['PXTIMEFLOWSTARTED_TIME'] =  pd.to_datetime(dataset.PXTIMEFLOWSTARTED_TIME, unit = 's' )
```

However, I just get the results below:

```
PXTIMEFLOWSTARTED_TIME

1970-01-01 11:15:38.220 
1970-01-02 12:35:25.529
```

Anybody could help me to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of format are those timestamps using…? Any information for context here?

Comment: I think you want just `pd.to_timedelta` instead of `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) as shown in below code:

```
# Input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'PXTIME': [40538.22, 131725.529]})
# Code to convert
df['PXTIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['PXTIME'], unit='s')

# Output dataframe
                  PXTIME
0 0 days 11:15:38.220000
1 1 days 12:35:25.529000
```

Comment: need to add `unit='s'`, otherwise it's assuming your passing it the number of nanoseconds.

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, I have updated the code and output dataframe accordingly.

Comment: @Nand, my problem is the correct GMT time should be:

`4:05:38 / 13:17:15`

However, when I try the conversion it is converting to 11 and 12.

Do you understand what I mean? 

Thank you!